# Laravel translate dynamic email (not with translate file)

Tags: laravel

I have a translation system with translate files, so I can translate every word on all my pages.
However, when I send an email, I write it in one language and I can't translate it in all of them. How to do when it is "dynamic" content?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show us some code or what you have tried. This question is way to generic to ever get a proper answer.

Comment: I have not tried anything, I would like to understand the method to use
I have a simplistic message table with "title" and "content", when I write a message from my form I write it in English, however I would like it to be in French too

Comment: How are you sending the emails and why can't you translate their content before sending?

Comment: How can I translate the content ? I need to sand many emails with different langages for different users who have different languages ?

Comment: How are you planning to send multiple emails? Are you going to send them one at a time in a loop? If yes then it should be simple to check the recipients' language (assuming you can determine this) and send the email in the corresponding language.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought, I write the email twice and send it in English or French depending on the language of the client.